# ajax выполнен успешно но php обработчик выдает null

Tags: php, ajax

ajax отрабатывает нормально, данные приходят НО php обработчик выдает null.

```
$.ajax({
url: 'test.php',         
type: 'POST', 
dataType: 'json',
data: {mas:'тупо текс'},     
success: function(data){ console.log(data); }
});
```

Файл test.php

```
echo json_encode($_POST['mas']);
```

Comment: включи debugger php и посмотри что у тебя в $_POST.....и ещё, после echo напиши `exit;`

Comment: PhpStorm нужен для openserver или можно без него?

Comment: Звиняюсь.. отправляешь как json, потом еще раз json_encode..а json_decode вообще есть ? )

Comment: json_decode нет

Comment: все равно null.

Comment: Как используешь json_decode покажи

Comment: $text = json_decode($_POST['mas']);
echo json_encode($text);

Comment: Проверил, выводится корректно что с json_decode, что без. Знач проверяй, что лежит в $_POST

Comment: проверил пустоту empty($_POST['mas']), походу пусто там.

Comment: и с чего вы вдруг решили тут, что в данном фрагменте кода требуется `json_decode`?

Comment: Да хоть с ним, хоть без него, хоть просто $_POST, null и всё тут.

Answer (score -2):

> [Комментарий](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.post.php#125651) говорит что $_POST используется для данных формы, в него нельзя передавать JSON/[XML](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.post.php#114598). Подтвердил это, передав данные через form_params в Guzzle как массив - данные появились в $_POST. Для получения JSON используйте php://input.